# how to deploy war in glassfish?

Tags: deployment, glassfish

i use "/opt/glassfish3/bin/asadmin deploy " to deploy war in glassfish

get the message

Remote server does not listen for requests on [localhost:4848]. Is the server up?
Unable to get remote commands.
Closest matching local command(s):
    help
Command deploy failed.

Comment: i got the method that does like this:

$GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin --port 8148 deploy apex.war

and input username and password the default user is admin and password is adminadmin

good luck for you!

Comment: looks like your GF server is down. Have you started it? /opt/glassfish3/bin/asadmin start-domain <domain-name>

Answer (score -1):

In my setup, I am using Cargo to deploy as described in the following question/answer: [How to deploy a Maven web application to a local-installed Glassfish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273099/how-to-deploy-a-maven-web-application-to-a-local-installed-glassfish/42273100#42273100)

I have a locally installed Glassfish 4.x server and a maven web application project (packaging=war). I am able to deploy using only the following commands:

```
mvn clean package cargo:deploy
```

or

```
mvn clean package cargo:redeploy
```

Comment: BTW: If you think the question has an answer somewhere else on Stack Overflow, please mark it as [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) instead of quoting the other answer.