# How to deploy a Maven web application to a local-installed Glassfish?

Tags: maven, deployment, glassfish

How one can deploy a maven web application to a locally instaled glassfish server using only maven plugins?

In other words, if I have a maven project with packaging=war, it is possible to deploy to a locally installed glassfish using a command like "mvn clean package some-plugin:goal-deploy"?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible using the [Cargo Maven Plugin](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Home.html), as it is self-explained in the following example:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>glassfish4x</containerId>
                    <type>installed</type>
                    <!-- Path to directory where glassfish is installed -->
                    <home>C:/programs/glassfish4</home>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <type>existing</type>
                    <!-- Path to domains directory -->
                    <home>C:/programs/glassfish4/glassfish/domains</home>
                    <properties>
                        <!-- Domain name where application will be deployed. -->
                        <cargo.glassfish.domain.name>domain1</cargo.glassfish.domain.name>
                        <!-- Glassfish user to authenticate -->
                        <cargo.remote.username>admin</cargo.remote.username>
                        <!-- Glassfish password to authenticate -->
                        <cargo.remote.password></cargo.remote.password>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The maven commands to deploy using plugin cited above are:

```
mvn clean package cargo:deploy
```

or

```
clean package cargo:redeploy
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a version of the plugin. Maven version 3 gives me some warnings about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and used the **asadmin** of Glassfish to deploy.

I just found the solution to the issue by adding this plugin to my `POM.xml`, using Maven plugin as you mentioned (followed link: https://alexjoz.gitbooks.io/code-life/content/chapter3.html)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
    <glassfishDirectory>D:\\Users\\admin\\GlassFish_Server_5.1.0\\glassfish</glassfishDirectory>
        <user>admin</user>
        <passwordFile>D:\\Users\\admin\\GlassFish_Server_5.1.0\\glassfish\\domains\\domain1\\config\\domain-passwords</passwordFile>
        <domain>
            <name>domain1</name>
            <httpPort>8080</httpPort>
            <adminPort>4848</adminPort>
        </domain>
        <components>
            <component>
                <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                <artifact>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.war</artifact>
            </component>
        </components>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <terse>false</terse>
        <echo>true</echo>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then I just clicked RUN and waited for the JSP page to show up.

My project info:

- Netbeans 12
- jdk 1.8
- Glassfish 5.1.0
- Spring MVC framework 5.2.2.RELEASE