# With maven, how to modify deploy files just prior to deploy phase?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have a maven project with one `war` and several `ear` projects.  Each `ear` project requires a slightly different `war`/`WEB-INF/web.xml`.  Each `ear`'s `pom.xml` uses `com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer` and `org.codehaus.mojo:truezip-maven-plugin` to replace tokens in the `web.xml`, and then place that new `web.xml` in the final `<project>-app.ear/web.war/WEB-INF`.  This all works great with building and creating the final EAR artifacts.

The problem I'm having is that when I `run` (using Netbeans, but that shouldn't matter), the `web.xml` used for deployment (`<project>/target/gfdeploy/first-app/web_war/WEB-INF/web.xml`) is the tokenized version.  I tried adding execution phases for `deploy`, but that doesn't work.

How can I ensure that the run deploy has the modified `web.xml` so I can test my app during development?

Here is the relevant parts of the ear `pom.xml`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-replace</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-replace</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>                                        
                <file>${project.parent.basedir}/${web.xml}</file>
                <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${web.xml}</outputFile>
                <replacements>
                    <replacement>
                        <token>@REALM_NAME@</token>
                        <value>${web.realm}</value>
                    </replacement>
                </replacements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>truezip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-replace-web-xml</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/${web.xml}</source>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/${web.zip}/WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
                            </file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-replace-web</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file> 
                               <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/${web.zip}</source>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.ear</outputDirectory>
                            </file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-replace-web-xml</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/${web.xml}</source>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/gfdeploy/${project.artifactId}/web-${project.version}_war/WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
                            </file>
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: What are the differences in those EAR / web.xml files ?  BTW. Why not putting the appropriate web.xml into the corresponding war module ?

Comment: The WAR is common to all EAR project, the difference only being the authentication realm. Each EAR has several EJB modules along with the common WAR. Some EJBs are common and included in all EARs, other are custom to the EAR that includes it.  The only difference right now in the <war>/WEB-INF/web.xml is the auth realm, as each realm needs to have it's own auth realm name.

Comment: Have you considered another approach like https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/mbeans-descriptors-howto.html?

Comment: Using Payara.  This is not a runtime issue, but a development issue.  Production builds are just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to keep your default **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml** fully functional for running during development. Then, keep a similar file called  **src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web-ear.xml** with all the replacement preparation.

Wrap all your replacement plugin strategy inside a maven profile and targeted to the **web-ear.xml** file. Add to this profile a maven-war-plugin configuration that will use the alternative **web-ear.xml** file during build, instead of the default **web.xml** (check: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>change-war-profile</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <!-- all your replacement plugins here -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web-ear.xml</webXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            <plugins>
        </build> 
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Make sure to activate this profile during the EAR maven build:

```
mvn package -Pchange-war-profile
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run your war with the jetty-maven-plugin choosing the run-war goal.
That goal run the packaged war.
See: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html#running-assembled-webapp-as-war

Comment: Jetty won't work. I need to run in a full EE profile container, as the EARs each have several ejb modules along with the WAR

Comment: have you considered to deploy your ear using maven and the cargo plugin instead of deploying it with netbeans ? See https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+plugin.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273099/how-to-deploy-a-maven-web-application-to-a-local-installed-glassfish?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *deploy* phase (of the build lifecycle) means *deployment* a production ready artifact to the remote Maven repository (e.g., Nexus or Artifactory). Roughly speaking, *artifact deploy* can be treated as *copying the artifact*. Read [the Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) for more details.

Secondly, Apache Maven does not support **application deploy** to the application server out-of-the-box. However, there are several ways to do it, depending on the application server you use. Which one do you use?

Special plugin can be found for JBoss Application Server - [jboss-as-maven-plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/). See [usage example](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/examples/deployment-example.html):

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.9.Final</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
        ...
    </build>
...
</project>
```

Similar plugin can be found for GlassFish Server: [glassfish-maven-plugin](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish-maven-plugin-legacy/).

Also, if this is acceptable for you, you can perform 2-steps **deploy** from Netbeans:

1. Build the project: run `mvn package` with all your plugins are configured at package phase.
2. Deploy the project: run application on the app server from Netbeans if it is supported (See [NetBeans Java EE Servers Support](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Servers) page).

Hope this helps.